# Ajax and Yii input

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, yii, yii-booster

I'm using the YiiBoostrap widget 'TbSelect2' to create a mutli-select box that allows you type in a textbox and select options to a filtered list.  Any selected are added into the textbox as a list.

This works when created on page load, however I need to use ajax to create the form inside a Yiibootstrap dialog to save page load times.
When I use ajax it instead creates a traditional multi-select box, the ugly awkward to use one.

The code is exactly the same, it even works in a dialog, it only doesnt work when i use ajax to call the php.  I'm sure there is something fundamental with YiiBooster that I'm missing, having never used it before.

but anyone know why this happens?  Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
echo $form->labelEx($modelFao,'For the attention of');
     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
         'asDropDownList' => true,
         'data' => $admins,
         'name' => 'faoids',
         'id'   => 'faoids',
         'htmlOptions' => array (
             'multiple'  => 'multiple',
         ),
         'options' => array(
             'placeholder' => 'disciplines',
             'width' => '80%',
             'tokenSeparators' => array(',')
)));
```

The exact code is copied and pasted to be used again in the ajax call

Comment: Any chance you can post a small self contained example of the problem code?

Comment: Added the code to the original post

Comment: there's an additional parameter to make sure the scripts and styles are output when you renderPartial, if not the additional js that is needed for that to work won't load